# Can 'must have -ed participle' have the present meaning?

Tags: tenses

In an Oxford dictionary, ‘must have –ed participle’ is used for supposing a past event.

> He must have known (= surely he knew) what she wanted.
>  I'm sorry,
>   she's not here. She must have left already (= that must be the
>   explanation)
>  [(Advanced Learner’s)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/must)

However, a case below seems to have some different meaning. Although, yet, I do not have found the explanation, from a grammar textbook for Korean language, I guess the case seems to express an awareness of realization, perfection, or the continuity of the perfection at present with a past form. Can my guessing be right, or am I to learn about some other explanation?

> “Jane,” he recommenced, as we entered the laurel walk, and slowly
>   strayed down in the direction of the sunk fence and the
>   horse-chestnut, “Thornfield is a pleasant place in summer, is it
>   not?”
>  “Yes, sir.”
>  “You **must have become** in some degree
>   attached to the house,—you, who have an eye for natural beauties, and
>   a good deal of the organ of Adhesiveness?”
> (Jane Eyre)

Comment: It's still in the past.

Comment: It's the same:  You must have become attached (= surely you became attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The present perfect can be used:

1.) to refer to a completed action in the past.

- She's left.

2.) to refer to a state that began sometime in the past and continues into the present.

- She's become attached.

The same applies when the present perfect is used with "must" to indicate a deduction:

- She must have left = I deduce that she has left. [The leaving is completed.]
- She must have become attached. = I deduce that she has become attached [and still is].